# How do I full join in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have two tables:
**T1**
1,a
2,b

**T2**
2,ggg
3,hhh

I want the join between them to give me all fields:

1,a,null,null
2,b,2,ggg
null,null,3,hhh

Comment: these are not all combinations. what exactly is the expected result?

Comment: @Alp: In terms of `FULL OUTER` there is nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL [doesn't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) have `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but you can emulate it e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id 
    WHERE T1.id IS NULL;
```

In general:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN = LEFT OUTER JOIN ∪ (RIGHT OUTER JOIN ∖ INNER JOIN)
```

You need to cut **one** inner join (in here from right join, but IMHO doesn't matter which one you choose), because both returns **same** inner joins. In here you have:

**T1:**:

[image]

**T2:**:

[image]

**LEFT OUTER JOIN:**:

[image]

**RIGHT OUTER JOIN:**:

[image]

**INNER JOIN:**:

[image]

**FULL OUTER JOIN:**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have a (combination of) columns that is unique, you can build a list of ids in a subquery.  Then you can use two outer joins to simulate a full outer join:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  col1
        from    t1
        union
        select  col1 
        from    t2
        ) ids
left join
        t1
on      ids.col1 = t1.col1
left join
        t2
on      ids.col1 = t2.col1
```